# function prototype error, non-void function

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I keep getting a strange compiler error for this bit of code:

```
double vector_length(double u1, double v1, double length)
{
length = pow(u1,2) + pow(v1,2);
length = sqrt(length);

}
```

Comment: For future reference it's a good idea to include any "strange compiler error" in the question as sometimes it's not quite as obvious as what you did here ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning anything from a function that claims to return a `double`.

You're also accepting three parameters by value, and immediately overwriting the last one, which is pretty pointless. If you want to communicate your "return" value via the 3rd parameter, you need to pass it by reference, and return `void` from the function.

So, either...

```
double vector_length(double u1, double v1) {
  double length = pow(u1, 2) + pow(v1, 2);
  length = sqrt(length);
  return length;
  // or simply return sqrt(pow(u1, 2) + pow(v1, 2));
}
```

or

```
void vector_length(double u1, double v1, double &length) {
  length = pow(u1, 2) + pow(v1, 2);
  length = sqrt(length);
}
```

Comment: +1 however may want to add a link to a tutorial or textbook as references are probably a new concept for OP